# Unsupported Protocol Scheme When Calling Chainlink Oracle

Tags: chainlink

I have just deployed a smart contract that uses a get request from my chainlink oracle.
In my contract it is called as shown below:

```
     Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    

    request.add("httpget", "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000/heartrate/api?code=1&zone=2&timeInterval=1d");
```

In my Chainlink Oracle, I am receiving the following error:

[image]

I suspect it might be to do with I am using httpgetwithunrestrictednetworkaccess as a task parameter in my Chainlink job spec and it is only supported for web types and not runlogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your smart contract, change:

```js
request.add("httpget", "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000/heartrate/api?code=1&zone=2&timeInterval=1d");
```

to

```js
request.add("get", "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000/heartrate/api?code=1&zone=2&timeInterval=1d");
```

To use adapters in your smart contracts, you can check the [chainlink adapters documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/adapters). The `httpgetwithunrestrictednetworkaccess` uses the same parameter as `httpget`, which in both cases is `"get"`